# Unable to create Xamarin project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a new Xamarin user, and have installed the Visual Studio 2015 Community installation, with all the Xamarin options enabled.  This was done on both a Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 machine, both of which were fresh installations.

On both PCs, I am receiving the same exact errors.  As soon as a Xamarin.Forms.Portable project is created, it loads with the following errors:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio multiple times, and made sure to install all features.  I also tried the steps highlighted [here](http://quabr.com/36640315/vs-community-2015-xamarin-warningide0006error-encountered-while-loading-the-p), to no avail.

I do not know how to proceed.  I am new to Xamarin, and need to create an application which works on both Android and iOS devices, so from what I can see, this is the project type I need to choose.

Is there something which I have missing, that needs to be installed? These errors are appearing as soon as a new project is created, so I'm assuming that the default configurations should be fine.

I also tried adding Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 through NuGet, however this in turn caused more errors.

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Runtime.dll, which can be found ~ C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\#YOUR .NET VERSION\Facades

Comment: @MalteR - I just tried doing that, however received an error message stating: "A reference to System.Runtime.dll could not be added.  This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Comment: Strange.. Have you tried create a Shared Asset Project? If so, do you experience the same problem?

Comment: @MalteR - I just tried doing so now on both PCs and received the same exact errors.

Comment: Very strange. Which version of Xamarin.Forms do you use?

Comment: @MalteR - I downloaded the latest version from Xamarin's website.

Comment: I'm also getting this error now in the Shared assets project: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)...

Comment: I added that DLL manually but after doing so, there are 73 errors now saying that Android-related packages do not exist. Which is not the case as Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 is added.

Comment: If you're missing android assemblies and support packages never add them manually, go to nuget and download them from there as it will restore the packages also from google repository. My advice is to remove all the packages from the project and then add them again from nuget, it would correct any missing library

Comment: In addition to @Gusman's suggestion, ensure you add the Xamarin.Forms package _first_.  Dependant on the version of Forms referenced it may have specific dependencies.  Likewise with updating packages.  Ensure you update Forms first and other packages later.

Comment: @Gusman and Alan Clark - Thanks to both of your suggestions - I have solved the errors in the .Droid project, however they remain in the .IOS project.  Is there anything else which needs to be installed?

Comment: How you solved the problem in the .Droid problem? that can give us a hint on what was happening and if you need to do something else on the .iOS project

Comment: @Gusman - I removed all references to Xamarin, and used NuGet to install Xamarin.Forms.  All errors disappeared, except for the ones targeting the .IOS project.

Comment: And you did the same on the iOS project? (remove all packages and references and reinstall the XamarinForms packages)?

Comment: @Gusman Correct, same thing with the iOS project but the errors persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These all appear to be warnings, not errors.  You should still be able to deploy to emulator or device.

The XamlCTask errors are probably related to the fact that, annoyingly, the versions of Xamarin Forms nugets are not aligned across the different platforms with a clean installation of VS2015 Community.  Right click on your SOLUTION, go down to Manage Nugets for Solution, and update Xamarin Forms. I was fighting these warning for a long time before figuring that out.

Do NOT update all Nugets -- packages are being pushed that are incompatible!  This was true recently in the Android universe -- updating all Nugets to latest stable would break your app.  This appears to be resolved now (I'm at the latest stable in all categories with working projects) but be mindful that you may need to roll back to "minimum required" rather than "latest stable" if you have errors.  A new issue has come up with the latest Xamarin Forms and 3rd party Nugets creating troublesome Resources.cs errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did as you suggested, but now the project is plagued with the following errors, right after updating the package: http://imgur.com/31GqFHz

Comment: This means you have not installed your Android SDKs appropriately.  Open your project, click on the Android download button in the Android tools bar http://imgur.com/mN8ZDha -- DO NOT download any of the pre-release SDKs, only the standard ones.  You'll need the build tools and the SDKs.

Comment: By Android download button, I mean the Android SDK Manager.  I was describing the icon.

Comment: They are already downloaded/up to date. Unfortunately the errors are still present. Just a reminder, that this is a fresh Visual Studio installation, as well as a fresh Android SDK install.  Some errors are also stemming from the iOS project too though, so not just Android.

Comment: Can you imgur your installed NuGets for the solution?

Comment: All errors are gone now - it appears that when adding a new Xamarin project, most of the NuGet packages are out of date.  I updated them all, and the errors vanished.